bnlearn library: Error in check.nodes(name, x) : invalid node(s) 'xNames'
I am using the caret::train() function to train a custom model with the bnlearn library.
The grid-search is defined over different algorithms that are implemented in bnlearn.
I get these warnings:
"model fit failed for Fold1: algorithm=hc Error in check.nodes(name, x) : invalid node(s) 'xNames'.
"
Warning message:
"model fit failed for Fold1: algorithm=tabu Error in check.nodes(name, x) : invalid node(s) 'xNames'.
"

The dataset used here is the UCI adult dataset and could be reproduced with
install.packages("mlr3fairness")
library("mlr3")
data("adult_test", package = "mlr3fairness")
adult_test <- adult_test %>% rename(income = target)

This is the part of my prediction function where I use the train function:
model <- caret::train(income ~ ., 
                   data = outer_trainData, 
                   method = bn_model,
                   tuneGrid = tunegrid, 
                   trControl = inner_control)

Here is my custom model:
# Define the custom model list
bn_model <- list(
  label = "Bayesian Network",
  library = "bnlearn",
  type = "Classification",
  
  parameters = data.frame(
    parameter = c("algorithm"),
    class = c("character"),
    label = c("Algorithm")
  ),
  
  grid = function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
    algorithms <- c("hc", "tabu", "gs", "iamb")
    
    if (search == "grid") {
      expand.grid(algorithm = algorithms)
    } else {
      data.frame(algorithm = sample(algorithms, len, replace = TRUE))
    }
  },
  
  fit = function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) {
  df <- as.data.frame(x)
  df$income <- y
  
  # Ensure consistent factor levels across folds
  df <- lapply(df, function(col) {
    if (is.factor(col)) {
      levels(col) <- union(levels(col), unique(col))
    }
    return(col)
  })
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  
  tryCatch({
    # Train the Bayesian network using the specified algorithm
    bn <- train_bn(df, param$algorithm)
    
    # Fit the parameters of the Bayesian network
    bn_fitted <- bn.fit(bn, df)
    return(bn_fitted)
  }, error = function(e) {
    print(paste("Error in fitting model:", e$message))
    return(NULL)
  })
},
  
  predict = function(modelFit, newdata, preProc = NULL, submodels = NULL) {
    if (is.null(modelFit)) {
      return(rep(NA, nrow(newdata)))
    }
    
    data <- discretize_df(newdata)
    predictions <- tryCatch({
      predict(modelFit, data)
    }, error = function(e) {
      print(paste("Error in prediction: ", e$message))
      return(rep(NA, nrow(newdata)))
    })
    
    return(predictions)
  },
  
  prob = NULL,
  
  predictors = function(x, ...) {
    colnames(x)
  },
  
  sort = function(x) x,
  
  levels = function(x) levels(x$obs)
)

And the functions used in the class are:
# Define cpdag_to_dag function
cpdag_to_dag <- function(cpdag) {
  adj_matrix <- amat(cpdag)
  ig <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_matrix, mode = "directed")
  if (igraph::is_dag(ig)) {
    return(cpdag)
  }
  directed_arcs <- directed.arcs(cpdag)
  undirected_arcs <- undirected.arcs(cpdag)
  while (nrow(undirected_arcs) > 0) {
    arc <- undirected_arcs[1, , drop = FALSE]
    cpdag <- set.arc(cpdag, from = arc[1, 1], to = arc[1, 2])
    undirected_arcs <- undirected.arcs(cpdag)
  }
  return(cpdag)
}

train_bn <- function(data, algorithm) {
  if (any(is.na(data))) {
    stop("The data contains missing values.")
  }
  
  # Train the Bayesian network using the specified algorithm with default BIC score
  if (algorithm =="hc") {
    bn <- bnlearn::hc(data)  # Using BIC by default
  } else if (algorithm == "tabu") {
    bn <- bnlearn::tabu(data)  # Using BIC by default
  } else if (algorithm == "gs") {
    bn <- bnlearn::gs(data)
    bn <- bnlearn::cpdag(bn)  # Convert to CPDAG
    bn <- cpdag_to_dag(bn)     # Convert CPDAG to DAG
  } else if (algorithm == "iamb") {
    bn <- bnlearn::iamb(data)
    bn <- bnlearn::cpdag(bn)  # Convert to CPDAG
    bn <- cpdag_to_dag(bn)     # Convert CPDAG to DAG
  } else {
    stop("Unsupported algorithm.")
  }
  
  return(bn)
}

# Define a function to evaluate the Bayesian network model
evaluate_bn <- function(testData, bn_fitted, target_var) {
  # Generate predictions for the target variable
  predictions <- predict(bn_fitted, data = testData, node = target_var)
  
  # Compare the predictions with the actual values in the test data
  actual_values <- testData[[target_var]]
  
  # Calculate the accuracy
  accuracy <- mean(predictions == actual_values, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  # You can also calculate other metrics such as:
  confusion <- table(Predicted = predictions, Actual = actual_values)
  precision <- diag(confusion) / rowSums(confusion)
  recall <- diag(confusion) / colSums(confusion)
  f1_score <- 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
  
  # Return a list of evaluation metrics
  return(list(
    accuracy = accuracy,
    precision = precision,
    recall = recall,
    f1_score = f1_score
  ))
}

